# Printing a score counter in greenfoot. Outputting zero

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am trying to output a score in the greenfoot IDE and all is working fine (the score is increasing) until I try to print it. When I try to print it it changes to zero for some reason.

**Crab Class:**

```
public class Crab extends Animal
{
    int health = 10;
    int score = 0;
    public void act()
    {
        score = score + 1;
        System.out.println(score);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newscore, "You lose!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("Left"))
        {
            turn(-3);
        }
        if (Greenfoot.isKeyDown("Right"))
        {
            turn(3);
        }
        if (canSee(Worm.class))
        {
            eat(Worm.class);
        }
        move();
        healthBar();
    }
    public void healthBar()
    {
        if (atWorldEdge())
        {
            Greenfoot.playSound("pew.wav");
            move(-20);
            turn(180);
            health = health - 1;
        }
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Message msgObject = new Message();
            msgObject.youLose();
            Greenfoot.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

**Message Class:**

```
public class Message extends Crab
{
    /**
     * Act - do whatever the Message wants to do. This method is called whenever
     * the 'Act' or 'Run' button gets pressed in the environment.
     */
    public void youLose() 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again next time. Your score was  " + score, "You lose!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }    
}
```

In the act method when I try to print out the score it shows it is increasing but when I print it out with `JOptionPane` or as normal at the end of the program it gives me 0.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZGOX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a completely new object to invoke your `youLose()` method on. By doing this, your score-counter will be set to zero again. You could try solving this by making a new constructor for Message that allows to pass the score.

```
public Message(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

PS: I don't see why it would be useful to make your Message class inherit from Crab

Comment: My message class inherits from Crab because that is the only way that my message class can get the score variable... I think. So where do I add that code?

Comment: The constructor belongs in the message class, but you should know there are some other (and better) ways to do what you want. Now you have to make a complete new object with fields that you actually barely use. You could always make a complete new class Message with a field score and you would get the same result. Even better would be to just make the `youLose()` method static and pass `score` as a parameter. (These aren't the only ways btw)

Comment: the error is because you have to pass your variable `score` to the constructor. You've hidden the default constructor by adding a new one, so you need to alter `new Message()` to `new Message(score)`. PS: don't forget to mark helpful answer as accepted

Comment: If I make the youLose method static and pass score as a parameter I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/h4DL9qk.png. If I alter Message() to Message(score) I have to do it in class where I create and use the youLose object as well. This class can't get the score variable. http://i.imgur.com/cr7n7Xz.png. Sorry if that didn't make much sense.

Comment: for the declaration of a method you need to state which datatype score should be. In this case your declaration should look like: `public static void youLose(int score) {...}` and again you would have to adapt your code to invoke this method and give it a parameter. I guess you'd better take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial) if you want to learn some more java, this is not the place.

Comment: that's what I mentioned to before as "you'll have to adapt your code to invoke this method". You invoke `youLose()` without parameters, but you just altered the definition of youlose() to ask for a parameter score. The new invocation should thus look like `youLose(score)`. Again I would advise you to learn java a little bit better before randomly applying inheritance etc...

Comment: Ok thank you, I know but this is for school and we haven't learnt other such things yet.

Comment: no problem, but know that people on stackoverflow normally don't help you solve your homeworks... I hope you don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. This way, this thread can be marked as answered.

Comment: It's not homework, it's just stuff I'm doing to help me learn. Thank you.